# MONGO_URL for running multiple Meteor apps on one server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-up

I have one Meteor application running on my Ubuntu server (Digital Ocean). I use Meteor Up (MUP) to deploy and keep the app running. Everything works fine.

However, when I try to deploy a second app on the same server, something goes wrong in connecting to the MongoDB. I get a long and unreadable error message that starts "Invoking deployment process: FAILED" and then ends with

```
Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
connected
myapp start/running, process 25053
Waiting for 15 seconds while app is booting up
Checking is app booted or not?
myapp stop/waiting
myapp start/running, process 25114
```

And the app refuses to run. I have tried a number of things to fix this and will edit this post if more info is requested, but I'm not sure what's relevant. Essentially I don't understand the Error message, so I need to know what the heck is going on?

EDIT:
I want to add that my app runs fine if I go into the project folder and use the "meteor" command.  Everything runs as expected.  It is only when I try to deploy it for long-term production mode with MUP that I get this error.

EDIT:
I moved on to trying mupx instead of mup.  This time I can't even get past the installation process, I get the following error message:

```
[Neal] x Installing MongoDB: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
Error response from daemon: no such id: mongodb
Error: failed to remove containers: [mongodb]
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container c2c538d34c15103d1d07bcc60b56a54bd3d23e50ae7a8e4f9f7831df0d77dc56: failed to create endpoint mongodb on network bridge: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: bind: address already in use
```

But I don't understand why! Mongod is clearly already running on port 27017 and a second application should just add a new database to that instance, correct? I don't know what I'm missing here, why MUP can't access MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky without your `mup.json` to see what's going on here. Given what you said, it looks like your 2nd app deployment tries to override/boot mongodb over the 1st one which is locked, the mongodb environment fails to boot, causing then the fail. You should tackle this different ways:

- If your objective is to share your mongoDB, point the MONGO_URL from your 2nd `mup.jon` on your first mongodb instance. It's generally something along the `2701X` ports. As it's a shared DB, changes in one database could affect the other.
- meteor-up oversees the deployment of your app from a meteor-nice-to-test thing to a node+mongodb environment. You can spawn another mongod instance with :
  `mongod  --port 2701X --dbpath /your/dbpath --fork --logpath /log/path` on your DO server and then point `MONGO_URL` there.
- Last but not least, `mupx` having `docker` under the hood. Using [mupx](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx) for your deployments should isolate both apps from each other.

Comment: Originally for both apps my mup.json files gave each app a unique PORT in the "env" variable, while leaving the MONGO_URL blank.  I assumed both apps would create databases (called by the app name) on the default mongod port 27017.  Since then I have tried a variety of other MONGO_URL values for the second app with no success. I will try mupx!

Comment: the PORT variable should have no effect on mongod instance since it just tells on which port your app listens to traffic. Setting a different MONGO_URL value for your second app won't work if you don't make sure a mongod instance is running beforehand on the url:port you are pointing at. Also, setting a mongodb can be really tricky, especially the auth/replicaset/oplog part so if you went through this, check you have correct rights too.

Comment: But yes, mupx should avoid all that :)

Comment: mupx will avoid all that because it automatically runs a mongod instance on the designated MONGO_URL, or because it automatically handles multiple databases on the default port?

Comment: Because it deploys within a separated docker environment for each app you deploy. See there: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx#server-setup-details